# How to replace a light fixture that has a 3-way light switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light-fixture

[image: Box 2]Box] I have a light fixture above a stairwell. There are two live switches that control it, one at the bottom of the stairs, one at the top. The wiring is relatively new about 25 years old (all copper, no knob and tube).

I removed the existing light fixture, which functioned well, with the intention to install a new fixture. I forgot to make notes on how the existing one was connected to the ceiling box. There are two black, two white wires, and one bare copper ground wire. One black wire is always live, it seems to be independent of the two switches. The other black wire and the two white wires are not live, independent of the two switches. I have a multimeter to measure the current.

I am confused as to how I am supposed to connect the new light fixture. Please help!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Good description, but adding a picture would probably help more.

Comment: Did you disconnect ALL the wires? Or just the two connected to the old fixture?

Comment: Is there a second light fixture which also lights as part of this circuit?  Have any other outlets or usage points lost power?   Take the cover off one of the 3-ways.  Are any of its screws live? Normally, 1 or 2 should be, depending on switch position.

Comment: I fully disconnected the light fixture. The wires are hanging out, per the picture.

Comment: There is no second light fixture, only one, which I completely disconnected. I haven't yet taken out either of the two switches.

Comment: Do the wires enter the light junction box in pairs, or are all the wires independent? In the USA 25 years ago most house wiring used flexible sheathed cables, with each cable carrying a black wire, a white wire, and a bare wire. Some cables carried a black, white, red, and bare wire.

Comment: Confirm: are you measuring current or voltage?

Comment: My multimeter can measure both. But I've been measuring only voltage so far.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 2):

So just to wrap this up. As a non-electrical engineer I couldn't figure this out. I got an electrician. He said it was not easy, as the original setup was not correct anyway. He found a workaround solution, and after 2-3 hours, finally got it to work. It was frustrating, and slightly costly, but I learned my lesson: always take the before pics, make notes before you take it apart.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  As an answer, though, this isn't a very actionable solution for other readers.  Can you add details (or is the solution the part about hiring an electrician)?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't have available time to dedicate to my problem. It took the electrician almost 3 hours, I can imagine that it would take me, a beginner, many weeks of trial and error. I wish I could add detail about the issue, but all I have is that the existing wiring was incorrect to begin with. I have used this electrician many times, so I took him at his word, but unfortunately I didn't ask for more detail. But pictures are key: I will take many, more than necessary next time!

Comment: Wow 3 hours to figure out a simple 3 way switch. I would not hire that electrician again just my opinion, if it did not work correctly prior to being opened I could see it taking a little time to trace the wires but 3 hours wow!

Answer (score 0):

Ok first you're going to have to take the cover plates off the two switches and take photos.

Chances are two of those wires are meant to be hooked together as the "traveler" between switches.  Or, perhaps, that one hot wire is power feed to this setup, you need send hot down some line (maybe the other black) for the circuit to work.  In that case one of the whites is neutral, the other is switched hot to the bulb.

You can see a bunch of wiring options for 3 way switches at https://www.easy-do-it-yourself-home-improvements.com/3-way-switch-wiring-diagram.html

Next time, take photo before!

Answer (score 0):

Usually two 3-way switch are wired 'top to top' 'bottom to bottom' and one common goes on live and other to the appliance. Neutral is given uninterrupted to the appliance.

so you have two wires going directly from a switch to the other, a permanent live on a switch and a controlled live (going to the light) on the other switch.

Get a test-light and see wich of the live is interrupted by (both) switches wire the new fixture to it and to the common neutral

Comment: Ok, I will take a picture and be back here in about 12 hours. I was hoping that the switches were good as is.

Comment: Why are we thinking about switches if it worked before the switches are right.